# Design issue with <h:panelGrid>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a code for aligning components inside the panelgrid which I have given below

```
      <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="table width100P"
                        columnClasses="width50P, width50P">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3"
                            columnClasses="leftColb, rightColb,rightColb"
                            styleClass="infoTable">
        // FIRST set of items which will be displayed in the first row since the panel grid column is "3".
            <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" />
            <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" />
 //THE BELOW IS AN DUMMY LABEL TO FULFILL THE PANEL GRID
                 <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" /> 



        // SECOND set of items which will be displayed in the SECONDE row since the panel grid column is "3".
            <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" />
            <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" />
             //THE BELOW IS AN DUMMY LABEL TO FULFILL THE PANEL GRID
                 <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" /> 



        //THIRD SET OF items which will be displayed in the THIRD row since the panel grid column is "3".
            <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" />


     //FOURTH SET OF items which will be displayed in the FouRHT row since the panel grid column is "3".
            <h:outputLabel value="PAT # :" />


        </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

```
CSS For the leftColb, rightColb,rightColb,width100P given below
```

```
 .infoTable TD {
        padding: 1px 2px;
        border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
        border-color: #ddd;
        border-style: solid;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .leftColb {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .rightColb {
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 50%;
    }

.width50P {
    width: 50%;
}

.width100P {
    width: 100%;
}
```

My problem is since the third set and the fourth set are having only one `<h:outputLabel>`, the first item in the fourth set jumps to the 3rd row to fullfill the panelgrid since its expecting three components in a row and the fifth item jumps to the     3rd row for tallying the row.

What i tried was to insert an "DUMMY"  in the third row to fulfill the panel grid when that row contains only two components, but there are another set of rows has 2 or 3 ,4 components which are rendered dynamically which made more difficulty in alignment.

**Since the panel grid allows three items in a row. I am trying to balance the components in each row.Though the rest of the rows components are dynamically generated.**

PFA of the screen shot which I have given below.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are being laid out by the default behavior of `p:panelGrid` (or in the example above `h:panelGrid`) with a set of numbered columns. Each component contained within the grid will be laid out from left to right, top to bottom.

If you want more control over what goes where use `p:row` and `p:column` to help define the structure of your grid. A good reference on how this is accomplish is in the PrimeFaces Showcase under [PanelGrid](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks a lot !!.But I want to implement the above using Panelgrid coz' in terms of design it looks great when Using Panelgrid in UI.

Comment: My suggestion is specific to `p:panelGrid`. Did you look at the PrimeFaces Showcase section that I linked in the last line of the last paragraph?